# как изменить название шапки программы в pyside2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Мне нужно изменить этот заголовок:

[image: заголовок]

как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

достаточно в коде прописать такую строку: `Dialog.setWindowTitle("gg")`
тогда он изменит название на "GG"